# I need to return a random string from a table of string values

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The code I'm trying to make is quite simple I want the Discord bot to respond with "yes" or "no" to the command "survey says?". For some reason or other it says that the value of a response can not be empty.

Here is the code:

```
} else if (message.content == "survey says?") {
    var Options = {
        [1] : "Yes",
        [2] : "No"
    };

    var Num = ( Math.random() * 1 + 2); // will return either 1 or 2

    console.log(Num);

    var Option = Options[Num];

    message.channel.send(Option);
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages

Comment: How to comapre Strings in Java

Comment: This looks more like javascript, because the array definition is not java.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead, and restructure your random number generator.

```
} else if (message.content == "survey says?") {
    var Options = ["yes", "no"];
    var Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

    console.log(Num);
    var Option = Options[Num];
    message.channel.send(Option);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `(Math.random() * 1 + 2)` will not return 1 or 2. It will return a number between 2 and 3. It means, `Option` will be undefined and you try to send it as a message, which is not allowed.

If you want a random element of an array of options (not sure why you used an object for `Options` though), you can use a helper function like this:

```js
function random(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}

const option = random(['yes', 'no'])

console.log(option)
```

And you could simplify your code like this:

```js
function random(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
}

// ...

} else if (message.content === 'survey says?') {
  const options = ['Yes', 'No']
  const option = random(options)

  message.channel.send(option)
}
```